# Validar conexión a internet con Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, api, kotlin

soy nuevo en Kotlin y desarrollo en Android, estoy validando la conexión a Internet con Kotlin, quiero usar volley para llamar a un API cuando esté conectado, basándome en codigos que e visto, llegue a tener esto:

```
class Network(val connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager) :
LiveData<Boolean>(){
 constructor(application: Application) : this(
     application.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
 )


    val networkCallback = @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(){

        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            super.onAvailable(network)
            postValue(true)

        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            super.onLost(network)
            postValue(false)
        }
    }

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
override fun onActive() {
    super.onActive()
    val builder = NetworkRequest.Builder()
connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(builder.build(), networkCallback)

}


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
override fun onInactive() {
    super.onInactive()
    connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
}

}
```

Hasta el momento estoy validandolo desde un activity de esta manera:

```
    private fun updateTbls(context: Context, url: String, httpResponse: HttpResponse){
    network = Network(application)
    network.observe(this,{isConnected ->
    if(isConnected){
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
        val url = "http://199.241.218.53:60000/VLVTI/Vistas/rrhh/action/variety_to_tareo.php"
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Conexion Correcta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { Toast.makeText(this, "Conecion Fallida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
        )
    }
}
```

Y cuando envío al activity no me notifica nada, sería de gran ayuda que me puedan brindar información o documentación de donde poder averiguar donde hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

[Kotlin : ¿Cómo comprobar la conectividad en Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57237708/250260)

Mediante la clase `ConnectivityManager` y su método `getNetworkCapabilities()` :

```
fun isConnected(context: Context): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        val capabilities =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
        if (capabilities != null) {
            if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR")
                return true
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI")
                return true
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)) {
                Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET")
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Este es un ejemplo de como usar el método anterior:

```
if(isConnected(context)){
    //Conectado.
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    val url = "http://199.241.218.53:60000/VLVTI/Vistas/rrhh/action/variety_to_tareo.php"
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            Toast.makeText(this, "Conexion Correcta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { Toast.makeText(this, "Conecion Fallida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
    )
}else{
    //No conetado.
}
```

Comment: Me sirvio, muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente Jose! , saludos!

Answer (score 0):

yo también soy bastante nuevo en esto, pero lo que me funcionó para comprobar si estaba conectado a la red por defecto fue lo siguiente:
Tengo un objeto con una variable que cambia según el estado de la red

```
object Variables {
var conexion=false}
```

Y lo siguiente es lo que comprueba la red y actualiza la variable, todo copiado claro, pero a mi me funciona.

```
val connectivityManager = getSystemService(ConnectivityManager::class.java)
    
    connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network : Network) {
            Log.i("onAvailable", "Conectado, The default network is now: " + network)
            Variables.conexion=true
        }

        override fun onLost(network : Network) {
            Log.e("onLost", "Desconectado, The application no longer has a default network. The last default network was " + network)
            Variables.conexion=false
        }

        override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(network : Network, networkCapabilities : NetworkCapabilities) {
            Log.i("TAG", "The default network changed capabilities: " + networkCapabilities)
        }

        override fun onLinkPropertiesChanged(network : Network, linkProperties : LinkProperties) {
            Log.i("TAG", "The default network changed link properties: " + linkProperties)
        }
    })
```

Y en realidad solo dejé los métodos onAvailable y onLost, los otros dos los borré, pero capaz te sirven para algo.

Corrección, al parecer onAvailable nos dice que esta conectado a una red, pero no necesariamente se tiene acceso a internet.
Creo que consultando a hasCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)
se puede consultar si la conexion efectivamente puede conextarse a internet.
En mi caso lo deje así:

```
connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network : Network) {
            Log.i("onAvailable", "Conectado, The default network is now: " + network)
            var habilitada= connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)?.hasCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)
            Log.i("desde enavailable","El estado de la red ${habilitada.toString()}")
            Variables.conexion=habilitada!!
        }
        override fun onUnavailable() {
            Log.e("onUnavailable", "Desconectado,desde onunavailable")
            Variables.conexion=false
        }
        override fun onLost(network : Network) {
            Log.e("onLost", "Desconectado, The application no longer has a default network. The last default network was " + network)
            Variables.conexion=false
        }
        override fun onLinkPropertiesChanged(network : Network, linkProperties : LinkProperties) {
            var habilitada= connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)?.hasCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)
            var inter=connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)?.hasCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
            Variables.conexion=habilitada!!
        }
    })
```

Al final, la variable inter (que no la estoy utilizando) nos dice que tiene capacidad de conectarse a internet, pero no necesariamente que tiene acceso (creo).
Quizás no es la mejor solución, pero para mi proyecto funciona.
Suerte!!